# Docker (Spring Boot or Thorntail) and Keycloak

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, keycloak, thorntail

i have a Problem Running Spring Boot and Keycloak both in docker containers.

I started with Keycloak with mysql as db running in docker.

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - testNetwork

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config/
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
      DB_ADDR: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: xxx
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: yyy
      KEYCLOAK_IMPORT_REALM: /keycloak/import/realm-import.json
    ports:
      - 8180:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - testNetwork
```

Then i added my realm (SpringBootKeycloak), my client (testclient), and a user with role 'user'.
After that i added spring-security to my Spring-boot-application. And edited my application.yml

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: 'off'
  application:
    name: testclient
    version: @project.version@
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testclient;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8180/auth
  realm: SpringBootKeycloak
  resource: testclient
  public-client: true
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
  security-constraints:
    - authRoles:
      - user
      securityCollections:
        - patterns:
          - /*
server:
  port: ${port:8090}
  rest:
    path: testclient
```

accoring to that i added my SecurityConfig:

```
  /**
   * Secure appropriate endpoints
   */
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/*").hasRole("user") // only user with role user are allowed to access
        .anyRequest().permitAll();
  }
```

Running my SpringBoot-Application locally is working fine.
I have to login with keycloak and get redirected to localhost:8090.
But when i add my SpringBoot-Application to my docker-compose and start it in a container i get still to keycloak for login, but when i should redirect i get a 403.

```
  testclient:
    image: testclient
    container_name: testclient
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n"
    build:
      context: testclient-application
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
      - 5006:5005
    networks:
      - testNetwork
```

with following container log:

```
{"@timestamp":"2018-08-16T11:50:11.530+00:00","@version":"1","message":"failed to turn code into token","logger_name":"org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator","thread_name":"http-nio-8090-exec-6","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)\n\tat java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)\n\tat java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)\n\tat java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)\n\tat java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)\n\tat java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)\n\tat java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)\n\tat org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)\n\tat org.keycloak.adapters.ServerRequest.invokeAccessCodeToToken(ServerRequest.java:111)\n\tat org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.resolveCode(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:336)\n\tat org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:281)\n\tat org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:139)\n\tat org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.authenticateInternal(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:203)\n\tat org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.authenticate(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:50)\n\tat org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.doAuthenticate(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:57)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:575)\n\tat org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n","app":"testclient","version":"1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"}
```

I can't figure out how to solve this...

EDIT 1: 
One more information: I'm running docker on Windows.

**EDIT 2: A SOLUTION**

My Working solution contains following:

1. Step, add keycloak as hosts

> To make things work, you’ll need to make sure to add the following to your hosts file (/etc/hosts on Mac/Linux, c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts on Windows).
>
> 127.0.0.1 keycloak
>
> This is because you will access your application with a browser on your machine (which name is localhost, or 127.0.0.1), but inside Docker it will run in its own container, which name is keycloak.

2. Step

Inner Docker port and published port needs to be same:

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - testNetwork

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config/
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
      DB_ADDR: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: xxx
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: yyy
      KEYCLOAK_IMPORT_REALM: /keycloak/import/realm-import.json
    ports:
      - 8080:8080   <--- edited
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - testNetwork
```

Step 3: keycloak definition in application.yml for Spring boot edited auth-server-url:

```
    keycloak:
  realm: SpringBootKeycloak
  auth-server-url: http://keycloak:8080/auth   <--- edited
  resource: testclient
  public-client: true
  security-constraints:
    - authRoles:
      - user
      securityCollections:
        - patterns:
          - /*
  ssl-required: external
  confidential-port: 0
```

The ugly thing coming with this solution:
You cant map your Docker Port onto another port to access from url.
  ports: 
    - 8080:8080
i spend a lot of time testing other combinations, with the result that the access url port has to be the same as inner docker port (8080 in my case).

EDIT 4:

***Same thing is working with Thorntail.***

To change the port for Keycloak add...

```
environment:
  JAVA_OPTS: "-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=10 -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

... for keycloak in docker-compose.
-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=10 sets default port (8080) + offset (10)
The rest are default values for keycloak.
Don't forget to edit "ports" and "auth-server-url"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your problem is `auth-server-url: http://localhost:8180/auth`. That `localhost` effectively has a different meaning when your app is running inside a docker container.

Inside the container it needs to be the name of the container i.e. `keycloak`. This is a bit awkward as when you connect to keycloak from your host machine you'd want to use `localhost` but the token issuer url needs to match to the url on which the token was requested (otherwise the token is rejected) so you end up having to put `keycloak` into your etc/hosts file.

You are in good company with this problem - I've encountered this [working with Activiti](https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-examples/tree/7-201712-EA). And you can find the [JHipster project dealing with it in the same way](https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#7) - they say:

> To make things work, you’ll need to make sure to add the following to your hosts file (`/etc/hosts` on Mac/Linux, `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows).
>
> `127.0.0.1 keycloak`
>
> This is because you will access your application with a browser on your machine (which name is `localhost`, or `127.0.0.1`), but inside Docker it will run in its own container, which name is `keycloak`.

Comment: thx for the quick answer. https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#7 did the trick i think.
As mentioned i added a host ('127.0.0.1 keycloak')  in c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts on Windows). Now i run into the next problem... I get an infinite redirection loop. My valid Redirect URI is "http://localhost:8090/*" ... i am still working on it, but maybe you will be so quick once more  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the question and the answer! I was struggling with this for quite sometime and getting connection refused error. The reason was because I was mapping 8180:8080, and as soon as I mapped **8080:8080** everything started working! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change exposed port you need to modify keycloak config in docker-compose:

```
  KC_HTTP_PORT: port_you_wanted
  KC_HTTPS_PORT: port_you_wanted
ports: 
 - "port_you_wanted:port_you_wanted"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).