# Confidential Rest-Api w/ Permissions - Always 403s - What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: node.js, docker, keycloak, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I've tried for many hours now and seem to have hit a wall.  Any advice/help would be appreciated.

**Goal:** I want to authorize the express rest-api (ex client-id: "my-rest-api") routes (example resource: "WeatherForecast") across various HTTP methods mapped to client scopes (examples: "create"/"read"/"update"/"delete"). I want to control those permissions through policies (For example - "Read - WeatherForecast - Permission" will be granted if policy "Admin Group Only" (user belongs to admin group) is satisfied.

Rest-api will not log users in (will be done from front end talking directly to keycloak and then they will use that token to talk with rest-api).

**Environment:**

- Keycloak 15.1.1 running in its own container, port 8080, on docker locally (w/ shared network with rest-api)
- "my-rest-api": Nodejs 16.14.x w/ express 4.17.x server running on its own container on docker locally. Using keycloak-connect 15.1.1 and express-session 1.17.2.
- Currently hitting "my-rest-api" through postman following this guide: https://keepgrowing.in/tools/kecloak-in-docker-7-how-to-authorize-requests-via-postman/

**What Happens:** I can login from keycloak login page through postman and get an access token. However when I hit any endpoint that uses keycloak.protect() or keycloak.enforce() (with or without specifying resource permissions) I can't get through. In the following code the delete endpoint returns back 200 + the HTML of the keycloak login page in postman and the Get returns back 403 + "Access Denied".

**Current State of Realm**

- Test User (who I login with in Postman) has group "Admin".
- Client "my-rest-api" with access-type: Confidential with Authorization enabled.
- Authorization set up:

  - Policy Enforcement Mode: Enforcing, Decision Strategy: Unanimous
  - "WeatherForecast" resource with uri "/api/WeatherForecast" and create/read/update/delete client scopes applied.
  - "Only Admins Policy" for anyone in group admin. Logic positive.
  - Permission for each of the client scopes for "WeatherForecast" resource with "Only Admins Policy" selected, Decision Strategy: "Affirmative".

**Current State of Nodejs Code:**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import session from "express-session";
import KeycloakConnect from 'keycloak-connect';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
app.use(session({
    secret: 'some secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: memoryStore
  }));

const kcConfig: any = { 
    clientId: 'my-rest-api',
    bearerOnly: true,
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
    realm: 'my-realm',
};
const keycloak = new KeycloakConnect({ store: memoryStore }, kcConfig);

app.use(keycloak.middleware({
    logout: '/logout',
    admin: '/',
}));

app.get('/api/WeatherForecast', keycloak.enforcer(['WeatherForecast:read'],{  resource_server_id: "my-rest-api"}), function (req, res) {
   res.json("GET worked")
  });

app.delete('/api/WeatherForecast', keycloak.protect(), function (req, res) {
     res.json("DELETE worked")
});

app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log(`server running on port 8081`);
  });
```

**A Few Other Things Tried:**

- I tried calling RPT endpoint with curl using token gotten from postman and got the RPT token perfectly fine, saw permissions as expected.
- I tried calling keycloak.checkPermissions({permissions: [{id: "WeatherForecast", scopes: ["read"]}]}, req).then(grant => res.json(grant.access_token)); from inside an unsecured endpoint and got "Connection refused 127.0.0.1:8080".
- I tried just disabling Policy Enforcement Mode just to see, still got Access Denied/403.
- I tried using keycloak.json config instead of object method above - same exact results either way.
- I tried openid-client (from another tutorial) and also got connected refused issues.
- I've tried using docker host ip, host.docker.internal, the container name, etc. to no avail (even though I don't think it is an issue as I obviously can hit the auth service and get the first access token).

I really want to use Keycloak and I feel like my team is so close to being able to do so but need some assistance getting past this part. Thank you!

------------------- *END ORIGINAL QUESTION* ------------------------

**EDIT/UPDATE #1:**
Alright so a couple more hours sank into this. Decided to read through every line of keycloak-connect library that it hits and debug as it goes. Found it fails inside keycloak-connect/middleware/auth-utils/grant-manager.js on the last line of checkPermissions. No error is displayed or catch block to debug on - chasing the rabbit hole down further I was able to find it occurs in the fetch method that uses http with options:

```
'{"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"localhost:8080","port":"8080","hostname":"localhost","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token","path":"/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token","href":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","X-Client":"keycloak-nodejs-connect","Authorization":"Basic YW(etc...)Z2dP","Content-Length":1498},"method":"POST"}'
```

It does not appear to get into the callback of that fetch/http wrapper. I added NODE_DEBUG=http to my start up command and was able to find that swallowed error, which appears I am back to the starting line:

```
HTTP 31: SOCKET ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)

    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
```

I then saw something that I thought may be related due to my docker network set up ([Keycloak and Spring Boot web app in dockerized environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213611/keycloak-and-spring-boot-web-app-in-dockerized-environment)) and tried change host name dns so I could use something other then local host but it didn't work either (even added to redirect uri, etc.).

**UPDATE #2:**
Alright so I got the keycloak.protect() (pure authentication) endpoint working now. I found through reading through the keycloak-connect lib code more options and it seems that adding "realmPublicKey" to the keycloak config object when instantiating keycloak-connect fixed that one. Still no luck yet on the authorization keycloak.enforce side.

```
const kcConfig: any = { 
    clientId: 'my-rest-api',
    bearerOnly: true,
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
    realm: 'my-realm',
    realmPublicKey : "MIIBIjANBgk (...etc) uQIDAQAB",
};
```

Comment: Can you share request which you send protected route by using postman?

Comment: @OnurkanBakırcı Thanks - yes in above code sample from nodejs I put two examples of the end points and in the "What Happens" section I describe their response in postman. If you are asking how I hit it in postman I linked the blog (under "Environment" section) I followed to set up postman auth, requests inherit oauth 2.0 from collection but other than that they are empty requests (just simple GET & DELETE - no params or body with default headers + auth headers oauth 2.0 adds.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my team finally figured it out - the resolution was a two part process:

1. Followed the instructions on similar issue stackoverflow question answers such as : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51878212/5117487
   Rough steps incase that link is ever broken somehow:

- Add hosts entry for 127.0.0.1 keycloak (if 'keycloak' is the name of your docker container for keycloak, I changed my docker-compose to specify container name to make it a little more fool-proof)
- Change keycloak-connect config authServerUrl setting to be: 'http://keycloak:8080/auth/' instead of 'http://localhost:8080/auth/'

2. Postman OAuth 2.0 token request Auth URL and Access Token URL changed to use  the now updated hosts entry:

- "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/abra/protocol/openid-connect/auth" -> "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/abra/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
- "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/abra/protocol/openid-connect/token" ->
  "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/abra/protocol/openid-connect/token"